# Attach Verticle position to Points position

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I have a simple geo-nodes setup
[image]

I created a grid and add mesh to points node to generate points on verticles. After that I animated position of the points and I now make verticles follow them. Does anyone know how can i do this: transfer points position to the nearest vertex?
[image]

thanks for helping !

Comment: As you explicitly define the offset (4 left-most nodes), why not simply *Set Position* your grid inside your *Simulation Zone* identically to the points ? With help of something like *Separate Components* and *Join Geometry*.

Comment: I want to use points like a hook for physics simulation. My goal is to simulate physics to points and attach original geometry position to points new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

As the *Mesh to Points* node is assigning the index of a vertex to the point spawned at the same position, a *Sample Index* node can be used to recover a point *Position* and to transfer it to the grid vertex sharing the same *Index*.

[image: GN Graph]

Resources: [image]

Comment: thank you so much! 
I am so happy right now as you helped me to get a solution

Comment: May I recommend to apply this : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)